# How to get version history of item using REST

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, version-history, api

Very new to SharePoint so I am sure this is a newbie question... I did look at the forums. Here is the command I am using:

```
https://Server/Site/_api/lists/getbytitle('Equipment%20and%20Inventory')/Items(471)/versions
```

But I get this error:

```
<m:error><m:code>-1,
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ResourceNotFoundException</m:code><m:message 
xml:lang="en-US">Cannot find resource for the request versions.
</m:message></m:error>
```

I have also tried this:

```
https://server/site/_layouts/15/versions.aspx?list={7ab286cb-0fc9-4ea7-b17e-2c08a6b9681a}&id=471
```

Which worked, but this just produces the page as if working on the site interface.. Not something that is easily harvester-able.

How can I get a item history in a format that a script can easily parse?

Answer (score 3):

What you're using works for me, but I'm in SharePoint online and you didn't mention a what version of SharePoint you're using. If I do:

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + 
        "/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('JobTitles')/items(1)/versions?$select=Title,VersionLabel",
    async: false,
    headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata'
    },
    complete: function(request) {
        console.log("CurrentUser: " + JSON.stringify(request, null, 4));
    },
    error: function(request) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(request, null, 4));
    }
});
```

The response JSON I get back looks like:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "Title":"Web Developer",
            "VersionLabel":"2.0"
        },
        {
            "Title":"Application Developer",
            "VersionLabel":"1.0"
        }
    ]
}
```

So no parsing necessary. Are you sure you have version history turned on for the list (List Settings->Version History, or Library Settings if it's a document library)?

Comment: If you've got "https://server/site/_layouts/15/versions.aspx?list={7ab286cb-0fc9-4ea7-b17e-2c08a6b9681a}&id=471" working, I guess the last question isn't really relevant.

Comment: in on premise 2013 the query is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Solution for SharePoint 2013 REST API:

```
https://{site_url}/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/siteName/Lists/listName/{itemID}_.000')/Versions
```

Comment: For some reason I'm getting empty XML tags. For example ```<author><name></name></author>```

Comment: What is your item's URL? How many versions this item has?

Comment: The URL is ```site + "_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/ajm/ajm-25/Mobile-Dev/Lists/Announcements_list/379_.000')/Versions"``` and there is only two versions.

Comment: What do you get without the `/Versions` at the end?

Comment: It gives me the data for everything else except for the ones I actually need which are the title, author, the actual comment.

Answer (score -1):

Try using SPServices:

```
$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetVersionCollection",
  async: false,
  strlistID: "Projects",
  strlistItemID: 1,
  strFieldName: "Description",
  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    $(xData.responseText).find("Version").each(function(i) {
      console.log("Name: " + $(this).attr("Description") + " Modified: " + $(this).attr("Modified"));
    });  
  }
});
```

**Sources**:

1. [SharePoint 2013 - Get SPListItem versions via REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423657/sharepoint-2013-get-splistitem-versions-via-rest/24428939).
2. [Any Rest API available for Version history of List item fileds?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/aspnet/en-US/33f9dc3d-be4d-489c-9f40-34aada8c73a2/any-rest-api-available-for-version-history-of-list-item-fileds?forum=sharepointdevelopment)